# Is there a way to inject keyboard events from a command line application?

Tags: dart

This might seem a little sketch, but I am trying to automate a minor inconvenience that I have.

Every day at the beginning of the day, I want to start a chat on skype with a certain group of people.

I created an app so I can just type `chat daily` at the command line and it will create the chat automatically. The issue is that it's just a blank chat and I need to start the chat with the same message. I want to be able to pass a `-m` flag to the app followed by the message that should be sent to everyone. The issue is being able to get that text into the skype chat.

Here are my thoughts on how this could be done:

1. Send Keyboard events so that the text entered into the text box and then sent in the chat.
2. Add the message to the clipboard, and subsequently paste the message. If I can't get it to send the text and I have to manually click `[enter]` I'm ok with that.
3. Lastly, if there's not a way to send keyboard events already, a much more involved approach would be to somehow emulate a keyboard to the system.

So basically I want to know if there's a way to control the clipboard of the system (copy/paste) or if there's a way to send keypresses to the system.

If you have any other ideas on how this, or if this, can be achieved, I'd like to hear.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Which OS? Windows?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that this will run on windows

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [win32](https://pub.dev/packages/win32) package, which has some bindings from the Win32 Windows Api to Dart, it has a ton of examples, but what you need should be something like this:

```
  final kbd = KEYBDINPUT.allocate();

  // Send the A key.
  kbd.wVk = VK_A;
  var result = SendInput(
      1, Pointer.fromAddress(kbd.addressOf.address), sizeOf<KEYBDINPUT>());
  if (result != 1) print('Error: ${GetLastError()}');

  kbd.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  result = SendInput(
      1, Pointer.fromAddress(kbd.addressOf.address), sizeOf<KEYBDINPUT>());
  if (result != 1) print('Error: ${GetLastError()}');
```

(from https://github.com/timsneath/win32/blob/master/example/sendinput.dart#L20-L30)